# First order approximation?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Why is always the first order approximation which is used.
I don't see the benefit of an inaccurate guess.
Computational wize i see the benefit, as it doesn't take that many differentiation to do, but otherwise?

> They are widely used in the method of finite differences to produce first order methods for solving or approximating solutions to equations.

From: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_approximation

Comment: "always"? I don't agree with that. The first order is used when that is all that is needed. If higher accuracy is required, higher order approximations are used.

Comment: Could you clarify your point ? Did you already hear about Halley or Householder or higher order methods ? Just post. Thanks.